# My terminal in VS Code won't print anything or give me an error. Don't know why it is not printing

Tags: c++, terminal, compiler-errors, printf

Just installed Visual Studio Code with C/C++ IntelliSense... (Microsoft) and Code Runner extensions. I am also using MinGW. This code refuses to print to my terminal.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("Hello World");

}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please copy and paste it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

While viewing this file press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Run Code` and press enter.
You should see a terminal opened with `OUTPUT` tab and see the result or an error.

If an error occurs publish it alongside with your question.